# Mergining Two Numpy Boolean Arrays after an Index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In my problem I have 2 boolean numpy arrays that I would like to merge after a given index. Currently I am using **np.logical_or(arr1, arr2),** but executes on the entire array. I am trying to only execute the operation after an index.

Below I would like to use **arr1** as the master and merge **arr2** after any **index**.

**For example, take the arrays and index below**

arr1 = np.array([ True, False, False,  True, False])

arr2 = np.array([False,  True,  True,  True,  False])

index = 2

**Returns**

*# array([True, False, True, True, False])*

Comment: `np.concatenate([arr1[:index], arr2[index:]])`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array slicing and np.concatenate to implement this. In this case, arr3 will consist of elements from arr1 in indices 0 to 'index' and the rest of the elements will be from arr2.

```
arr1 = np.array([ True, False, False, True, False])
arr2 = np.array([False, True, True, True, False])

index = 2

arr3= np.concatenate((arr1[:index], arr2[index:]), axis = 0)

print(arr3)
```